# How to add more comments on existing excel file that containing comments using apache poi?

Tags: apache-poi

I have one problem in Apache poi for putting commands in excel sheet.

My existing Excel sheet having some more comments abt the cell.Now, i want to open my existing excel file and also put some more comments abt the other cells.While doing so, the old comments are removed.after opening the excel file,it says,"file error:Data may have been lost"...

Please guide me to put more comments on my existing excel sheet....

Comment: it's not working on my code either. this could be a bug in POI. check the mailing lists

Comment: Thanks Jose. I have also tried lot of times.But i wasn't able to do that.Ok, as per u said, i will check  the mailling list in apache poi and let u know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Apache POI3.6.This is a permanent bug in that version.But i dont know whether it is supported by 7 or not...